# H2 database generated in wrong directory when generated with maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, h2

I have the following project structure

```
project/
├─ frontend/
├─ backend/
│  ├─ src/main/resources/
│  │  ├─ application.yml
```

My application.yml contains:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:./database
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
```

If I run some maven goal (e.g. `maven clean compile`), the database files are created under `project` instead of `backend`.

Do I need to configure my maven environment in a way that it knows where the project root is?

Answer (score 0):

Your url says to make it in the current location:  `./database`

That location seems to be the project base.

You don't say how you are starting it, so there is little more that can be said.